# Stationarise data in a loop

Tags: r, filter, dynamic, statistics

I'm trying to apply a filter to stationarise data, and then calculate a dynamic factor model using the stationarised data.

This is my approach

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(countrycode)
library(dfms)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(neverhpfilter)
library(OECD)
library(tidyr)

cbind.fill <- function(...){
  nm <- list(...) 
  nm <- lapply(nm, as.matrix)
  n <- max(sapply(nm, nrow)) 
  do.call(cbind, lapply(nm, function (x) 
    rbind(x, matrix(, n-nrow(x), ncol(x))))) 
}


kei=get_dataset("KEI")
kei=kei[kei$FREQUENCY=="M",]
kei=kei[kei$MEASURE=="GP",]

kei=kei[kei$Time>="1983-01",]

kei=kei[,c("FREQUENCY", "LOCATION", "MEASURE", "ObsValue", "SUBJECT", "Time")]

kei_long=kei %>% distinct() %>% pivot_wider(., names_from = SUBJECT, values_from = ObsValue)

colnames(kei_long)=c("freq", "country", "measure", "time", "exports", "imports", "share_pries", "construction",
                     "retail_sales", "employment","earnings_hourly", "consumper_prices", 
                     "industrial_production", "sales", "intermediate_rates", "long_rates", 
                     "exchange_rates", "short_rate", "leading_indicator", "leading_ind_gdp",
                     "unemployment", "money3", "producer_price_index", "money_aggregates", "consumer_confidence", 
                     "business_confidence")
kei_long=kei_long[,-c(1,3)]

kei_long <- subset(kei_long, !country %in% c("G-20", "G-7", "OECD", "OECDE"))

# Convert the country codes to country names
kei_long$country <- countrycode(kei_long$country, origin = "iso3c", destination = "country.name")

kei_long[, 3:ncol(kei_long)] <- lapply(kei_long[, 3:ncol(kei_long)], as.numeric)

sheet_names[3]="United States"

kei_long <- subset(kei_long, country %in% sheet_names )

econ_data <- split(kei_long, kei_long$country)

countries_total=names(econ_data)

dfm_econ <- list()
summaries_list=list()

for (this_country in countries_total) {
 data_temp= econ_data[[this_country]]
 #data_temp=tsnarmimp(data_temp, max.missing = 0.3, na.rm.method = "all", na.impute="median.ma.spline", ma.terms = 5)
 data_temp$time=ym(data_temp$time)
 data_temp=as.xts(data_temp)
 data_temp=data_temp[,-1]
 storage.mode(data_temp) <- "numeric"
 
 data_temp=data_temp[, which(colMeans(!is.na(data_temp)) > 0.5)]
 
 # stationarize?--> same treatment across the board, hamilton filters

 country_cols=colnames(data_temp)
 country_stat=list()
 for (this_col in country_cols) {
   data_col=data_temp[,this_col]
   this_col_stat= yth_filter(100 * log(data_col), h = 8, p = 4, output = c("cycle"))
   country_stat[[this_col]]=this_col_stat
   
 }
 data_temp=as.data.frame(data_temp)
 this_country_dfm=DFM(data_temp,1,1,tol = 1e-08, max.iter = 15000L)
 dfm_econ[[this_country]] <- this_country_dfm
 summaries_list[[this_country]]=summary(this_country_dfm)
  
}
```

The idea is pretty simple: I have a bunch of countries, and I need to stationarise each variable separately. I rather do it with a loop instead of having to do each by hand.
Now, after I stationarize the variables, I need to summarize them using a dynamic factor model.
I need to store the cyclical version of each variable, and then the dfm

Thanks!